# anchor tag (a tag) onclick event handler not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Though i have included the onclick handler for the *a* tag in the html returned by the render method of the reactjs component(component with the name renderLocationLink) , though the rendering takes place correctly the onclick handler attribute doesnt appear in the rendered html on the webpage  .I want the  Not able to figure whats the issue , here is the code

```
var feedApp = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function(){
        return {
          data : [
           {display_name:"Rao",content:"this is Rao post",links:['link1','link2','link3']},
           {display_name:"Sultan",content:"this is Sultans",links:['link4','link5','link6']},
           {display_name:"John",content:"this is John post",links:['link7','link8','link9']}
          ]
        }
      },
      fetchFeedsFromUrl: function(){
        console.log('Onclick triggered');
      },
      render: function(){
        return (<Feeds data={this.state.data} onClick={this.fetchFeedsFromUrl} />)
      }
})

var Feeds = React.createClass({

    render: function(){
      var onClickfunc = this.props.onClick; 
      var feeds = this.props.data.map(function(feed){
        return (
          <oneFeed  name={feed.display_name}  onClick={this.onClickfunc} content={feed.content}  links={feed.links} />
        )
      });
    return( 
      <div> {feeds} </div>  
    )
  }
})


var oneFeed = React.createClass({
      render: function() {
        return (
         <div> 
          <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
          <renderLocationLink  onClick={this.props.onClick}  linkArray={this.props.links}  />
          <p>{this.props.content} </p>
         </div> 
        )
      }
    });


var renderLocationLink = React.createClass({

  render: function(){
    var onClick = this.props.onClick;
    var locationLinks = this.props.linkArray.map(function(link,index){
        return (<a onClick={this.onClick} href={link}>{link}   </a>)
    })

   return ( <div >{locationLinks}</div> )

  }
})

React.renderComponent(feedApp(null),document.body);
```

Comment: Is the issue that the ```onClick``` attribute is not present in your rendered markup, or is the issue that the handler doesn't seem to work?

Comment: @DanielApt ,both the cases are true , the onClick is not present in the rendered markup and its not working too ....

Comment: Alright, well it never will be present in the rendered markup. You probably are passing the property down only so far, and the property never reaches the intended child component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to reference "this" in your map functions to access your local variable.  Remove "this" when you try to access the onClick variable.

```
var renderLocationLink = React.createClass({

  render: function(){
    var onClick = this.props.onClick;
    var locationLinks = this.props.linkArray.map(function(link,index){
        return (<a onClick={onClick} href={link}>{link}   </a>)
    })

   return ( <div >{locationLinks}</div> )

  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Your rendered markup will not contain an `onClick` attribute. What you write in your JSX markup is not a direct HTML markup.

What will happen instead is that React will give your markup a `data-reactid` attribute, and will make sure its own event handlers fire something when a specific `data-reactid` gets clicked.

Comment: But how to fix this code such that it would execute/call the function with onClick of the anchor tag ??

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I have found out where it goes wrong:

In many components you were using `this` incorrectly. You were using `this` within the render function. So instead of using
`{this.onClick}` you should have been using `{onClick}` instead.

Look at this example, how we use `{onClick}` (and not `{this.onClick}`) in the returned render.

```
var Feeds = React.createClass({

    render: function(){
      var onClickfunc = this.props.onClick;
      var feeds = this.props.data.map(function(feed){
        return (
          <oneFeed  name={feed.display_name}  onClick={onClickfunc} content={feed.content}  links={feed.links} />
        )
      });
    return( 
      <div> {feeds} </div>  
    )
  }
})
```

Here's a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/6771/

PS: This is exactly as [Butters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3617959/butters) suggested.